# x2go connects, starts session, but client drops

Tags: ssh, nx, nomachine, x2go

I am trying to connect x2go server. Nomachine and ssh works fine. I can also connect (x2go) to a virtual machine installed on the physical server (network bridged, so I guess network is not the source of the problem).

What happens is; After entering password on client, the session starts and I can see it using x2golistsessions. But the client then drops back to authentication prompt without starting any window.

Is there something that could go wrong with the encoding?
When I check  x2goclient --debug, I see lots of escape codes which are different than a successful connection. For example, the first difference (compared to successful connection) seems to be:

```
   LOGIN CHECK:"basename: invalid option -- 'c'\r\nTry 'basename --help' for more information.\r\n"
   LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[124;1H"
   LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m"
   LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"                   
   LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
```

Any help/direction to find the problem is appreciated. Full log is below.
Thanks in advance.

```
x2go-INFO-8> "Starting connection to server: 172.22.0.12:22"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:2853> Starting new ssh connection to server:"172.22.0.12":"22" krbLogin: false
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:168> SshMasterConnection, host "172.22.0.12"; port 22; user "ilker"; useproxy false; proxyserver ""; proxyport 22
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:248> Starting SSH connection without Kerberos authentication.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:250> SshMasterConnection, instance SshMasterConnection(0x7fdcc400dca0) created.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:495> SshMasterConnection, instance SshMasterConnection(0x7fdcc400dca0) entering thread.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:797> Session port before config file parse: 22
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:807> Session port after config file parse: 22
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:870> Session port before config file parse (part 2): 22
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:880> Session port after config file parse (part 2): 22
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:904> cserverAuth
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:943> state: 1

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1218> Trying password mechanism if available.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1222> Password mechanism available. Continuing.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:687> User authentication OK.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"basename: invalid option -- 'c'\r\nTry 'basename --help' for more information.\r\n"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[124;1H"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3051> SSH Session prompt:"basename: invalid option -- 'c'\r\nTry 'basename --help' for more information.\r\n"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3054> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[124;1H"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1708> LOGIN CHECK:"\u001B[0mLOGIN OK\r\n"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1711> don't have interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1744> LOOP FINISHED
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1748> No interaction needed, continue session
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:702> Login Check - OK
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3068> SSH Session interaction
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3077> SSH Interaction update:"\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:2947> SSH connection established.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3374> Continue normal X2Go session
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:199> Executing remote command via SshProcess object 0: "x2golistsessions"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:213> this=SshProcess(0x55d915294080) Running masterCon->addChannelConnection(this, '"a93791ef-1378-4114-80b6-e44f293b8a7a"', '"bash -l -c 'echo \"X2GODATABEGIN:a93791ef-1378-4114-80b6-e44f293b8a7a\"; export PATH=\"/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin\";export TERM=\"dumb\"; x2golistsessions; echo \"X2GODATAEND:a93791ef-1378-4114-80b6-e44f29"');
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1810> Locking SSH channel connection MUTEX.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1812> Passing new channel connection object to channelConnections.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1814> Unlocking SSH channel connection MUTEX.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1977> Creating new channel.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1990> New channel:0x7fdc9400eea0

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2065> Executing remote: "bash -l -c 'echo \"X2GODATABEGIN:a93791ef-1378-4114-80b6-e44f293b8a7a\"; export PATH=\"/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin\";export TERM=\"dumb\"; x2golistsessions; echo \"X2GODATAEND:a93791ef-1378-4114-80b6-e44f293b8a7a\";'"

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2082> New exec channel created.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2121> EOF on channel 0x7fdc9400eea0; SshProcess object: 0
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2222> EOF sent.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2224> Channel closed.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:532> SSH finished: raw output (stdout): "\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0mX2GODATABEGIN:a93791ef-1378-4114-80b6-e44f293b8a7a\n\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0mX2GODATAEND:a93791ef-1378-4114-80b6-e44f293b8a7a\n"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:543> SSH finished: true - "\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m" (0).
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3861> "\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:4521> Executing remote command: "X2GODPI=123 X2GO_XINERAMA=no x2gostartagent 1280x1024 adsl 16m-jpeg-9 unix-kde-depth_24 us auto 1 R TERMINAL none"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:199> Executing remote command via SshProcess object 1: "X2GODPI=123 X2GO_XINERAMA=no x2gostartagent 1280x1024 adsl 16m-jpeg-9 unix-kde-depth_24 us auto 1 R TERMINAL none"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:213> this=SshProcess(0x55d915882970) Running masterCon->addChannelConnection(this, '"c453e3aa-45de-415d-acc9-a8481a93f042"', '"bash -l -c 'echo \"X2GODATABEGIN:c453e3aa-45de-415d-acc9-a8481a93f042\"; export PATH=\"/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin\";export TERM=\"dumb\"; X2GODPI=123 X2GO_XINERAMA=no x2gostartagent 1280x1024 adsl 16m-jpe"');
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1810> Locking SSH channel connection MUTEX.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1812> Passing new channel connection object to channelConnections.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1814> Unlocking SSH channel connection MUTEX.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1977> Creating new channel.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1990> New channel:0x7fdc9400bc80

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2065> Executing remote: "bash -l -c 'echo \"X2GODATABEGIN:c453e3aa-45de-415d-acc9-a8481a93f042\"; export PATH=\"/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin\";export TERM=\"dumb\"; X2GODPI=123 X2GO_XINERAMA=no x2gostartagent 1280x1024 adsl 16m-jpeg-9 unix-kde-depth_24 us auto 1 R TERMINAL none; echo \"X2GODATAEND:c453e3aa-45de-415d-acc9-a8481a93f042\";'"

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2082> New exec channel created.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2121> EOF on channel 0x7fdc9400bc80; SshProcess object: 1
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2222> EOF sent.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2224> Channel closed.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:532> SSH finished: raw output (stdout): "\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0mX2GODATABEGIN:c453e3aa-45de-415d-acc9-a8481a93f042\n\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m50\n094fed4ba93c52ac875d3eb598cde727\n103522\nilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24\n37833\n37834\n37835\n\u001B[0mX2GODATAEND:c453e3aa-45de-415d-acc9-a8481a93f042\n"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:543> SSH finished: true - "\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m50\n094fed4ba93c52ac875d3eb598cde727\n103522\nilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24\n37833\n37834\n37835\n\u001B[0m" (1).
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:5425> Agent output: "\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m50\n094fed4ba93c52ac875d3eb598cde727\n103522\nilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24\n37833\n37834\n37835\n\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:387> Starting tunnel via SshProcess object 2: "localhost":37833 -> "localhost":38833

RESUMING SESSION is KDRIVE:  false
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:6142> "Starting NX proxy, command: nxproxy -S nx/nx,options=/home/ilker/.x2go/S-ilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24/options:\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m50"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:157> Direct tunnel: waiting for connections on "localhost":38833
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:6618> Proxy wrote on stderr: "Loop: PANIC! Can't identify NX port in string ':\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m50'.\nError: Can't identify NX port in string ':\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m50'.\n"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:11075> Generating SSH key. Type: "RSA"; Location: "/home/ilker/.x2go/ssh/gen/key.EQtPVR"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in /home/ilker/.x2go/ssh/gen/key.EQtPVR
Your public key has been saved in /home/ilker/.x2go/ssh/gen/key.EQtPVR.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:UoRMa4zRd9AI9a1HigontfGv/mhq76KQ2rI6eGJMog4 X2Go Client RSA user key
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 4096]----+
|    .+o+++       |
|     ++oo.o.     |
|    . *.... o    |
|     o = . +     |
|    o + S o .    |
|.. . + o . .     |
|E o   .   .      |
|B=..  o .o       |
|BB. .o.B*..      |
+----[SHA256]-----+
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:8655> Key created on: "/home/ilker/.x2go/ssh/gen/key.EQtPVR"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:9990> Starting Folder Sharing tunnel for: "ilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:9991> FS port: "37835"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:387> Starting tunnel via SshProcess object 3: "localhost":37835 -> "127.0.0.1":7022

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:426> Requesting reverse tunnel from port 37835 to 7022
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:310> Copying file via SshProcess object 4: "/home/ilker/.x2go/ssh/gen/key.EQtPVR" -> "~ilker/.x2go/ssh/key.EQtPVR"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:199> Executing remote command via SshProcess object 5: "x2gobasepath"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:213> this=SshProcess(0x55d915943e20) Running masterCon->addChannelConnection(this, '"a8b07467-6b29-4123-bf99-33b4ca90f732"', '"bash -l -c 'echo \"X2GODATABEGIN:a8b07467-6b29-4123-bf99-33b4ca90f732\"; export PATH=\"/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin\";export TERM=\"dumb\"; x2gobasepath; echo \"X2GODATAEND:a8b07467-6b29-4123-bf99-33b4ca90f7"');
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1810> Locking SSH channel connection MUTEX.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1812> Passing new channel connection object to channelConnections.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1814> Unlocking SSH channel connection MUTEX.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:6475> Deleting Proxy.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:6520> Waiting for proxy to exit.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:6544> Checking exit status.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:199> Executing remote command via SshProcess object 6: "x2gocmdexitmessage ilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:213> this=SshProcess(0x55d9158dc5e0) Running masterCon->addChannelConnection(this, '"d8eaf3d5-15a0-4aff-b849-c6e52323f667"', '"bash -l -c 'echo \"X2GODATABEGIN:d8eaf3d5-15a0-4aff-b849-c6e52323f667\"; export PATH=\"/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin\";export TERM=\"dumb\"; x2gocmdexitmessage ilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24; echo \"X2G"');
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1810> Locking SSH channel connection MUTEX.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1812> Passing new channel connection object to channelConnections.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1814> Unlocking SSH channel connection MUTEX.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:6601> Finished proxy.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:328> Listening for TCP/IP connections on 37835
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1840> SSH Master Connection copy - dst path:".x2go/ssh" file:"key.EQtPVR"

x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:10035> FS tunnel through SSH seems to be up and running ...

x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:11659> "Searching proxy window: X2GO-ilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:13278> "Searching window with title: X2GO-ilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1850> Error initializing SCP session: SCP: invalid status code 27 received

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1977> Creating new channel.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1990> New channel:0x7fdc94009d90

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2065> Executing remote: "bash -l -c 'echo \"X2GODATABEGIN:a8b07467-6b29-4123-bf99-33b4ca90f732\"; export PATH=\"/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin\";export TERM=\"dumb\"; x2gobasepath; echo \"X2GODATAEND:a8b07467-6b29-4123-bf99-33b4ca90f732\";'"

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2082> New exec channel created.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1977> Creating new channel.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1990> New channel:0x7fdc9400eb80

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2065> Executing remote: "bash -l -c 'echo \"X2GODATABEGIN:d8eaf3d5-15a0-4aff-b849-c6e52323f667\"; export PATH=\"/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin\";export TERM=\"dumb\"; x2gocmdexitmessage ilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24; echo \"X2GODATAEND:d8eaf3d5-15a0-4aff-b849-c6e52323f667\";'"

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2082> New exec channel created.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1840> SSH Master Connection copy - dst path:".x2go/ssh" file:"key.EQtPVR"

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1850> Error initializing SCP session: SCP: invalid status code 27 received

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1840> SSH Master Connection copy - dst path:".x2go/ssh" file:"key.EQtPVR"

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1850> Error initializing SCP session: SCP: invalid status code 27 received

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2165> EOF on channel 0x7fdc9400eb80; SshProcess object: 6
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2222> EOF sent.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2224> Channel closed.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2165> EOF on channel 0x7fdc94009d90; SshProcess object: 5
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2222> EOF sent.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2224> Channel closed.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1840> SSH Master Connection copy - dst path:".x2go/ssh" file:"key.EQtPVR"

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:532> SSH finished: raw output (stdout): "\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0mX2GODATABEGIN:d8eaf3d5-15a0-4aff-b849-c6e52323f667\n\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0mX2GODATAEND:d8eaf3d5-15a0-4aff-b849-c6e52323f667\n"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:543> SSH finished: true - "\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m" (6).
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:9933> "Command message: \u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m\u001B[0m"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:764> SshMasterConnection, instance SshMasterConnection(0x7fdcc400dca0) waiting for thread to finish.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1850> Error initializing SCP session: SCP: invalid status code 27 received

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1908> Disconnecting ...

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1917> Deleting channel connections.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1923> Disconnecting session.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1927> Deleting sockets.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1932> All channels closed and session disconnected. Quitting session loop.

x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:766> SshMasterConnection, instance SshMasterConnection(0x7fdcc400dca0) thread finished.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:52> SshProcess destructor called.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:52> SshProcess destructor called.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:52> SshProcess destructor called.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:52> SshProcess destructor called.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:52> SshProcess destructor called.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:52> SshProcess destructor called.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:52> SshProcess destructor called.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:771> SshMasterConnection, instance SshMasterConnection(0x7fdcc400dca0) finished destructor.
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:11659> "Searching proxy window: X2GO-ilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:13278> "Searching window with title: X2GO-ilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:11659> "Searching proxy window: X2GO-ilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:13278> "Searching window with title: X2GO-ilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:11659> "Searching proxy window: X2GO-ilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:13278> "Searching window with title: X2GO-ilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:11659> "Searching proxy window: X2GO-ilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:13278> "Searching window with title: X2GO-ilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:11659> "Searching proxy window: X2GO-ilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24"
x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:13278> "Searching window with title: X2GO-ilker-50-1632309246_stRTERMINAL_dp24"
```

Comment: What is the garbage that your ssh server sends when you log in?

Comment: in the logs  I only see an ssh connection and then a disconnection message. But no errors.

Comment: ssh to the server yourself and look at what output appears before your shell prompt. Better, capture it in a `script` session.